# StatusIcon doesn't appear in notification area

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm using following code to display a notfication icon in ubuntu 11.10 (gtk-sharp 2.12)

```cs
StatusIcon icon = StatusIcon.NewFromStock(Stock.Harddisk);
icon.Visible = true;
```

but the icon does not appear.

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer releases of Ubuntu (using Unity) use a new system/library for notification icons called [Application Indicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators) using the appindicator library. I suggest you look at using appindicator-sharp to create the indicator. You can see a sample patch for how it was implemented in Tomboy [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/497058/comments/1). In order to have something that works for both Unity/Ubuntu and other traditional desktop environments, I suggest you take an approach similar to the one in Tomboy where at runtime you detect which style "notification icon" you should create.